# Tkinter - How to change the color of the frame when input field is satisfied using grid

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, grid, frame

I am trying to get the color of the frame to change to black if the user inputs "b", green if the user inputs "g". This is what i have thus far

Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("250x300-1200-400")
        frame = Frame(root)

        # input field stored
        self.input_a = StringVar()

        # input field
        input_color_changer = Entry(root, textvariable=self.input_a)
        input_color_changer.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button = Button(root, text="Run", command=self.ColorChanger)
        button.grid(row=1, column=2)


        root.mainloop()


    def ColorChanger(self):
        input_b = self.input_a.get()


        if input_b == "b":
            print("BLACK") # CHANGE COLOR OF FRAME TO BLACK
        if input_b == "g":
            print("GREEN") # CHANGE COLOR OF FRAME TO GREEN etc...

Main()
```

Comment: What's stopping you from changing the color of the frame?

Comment: you have to use `self.` and `self.frame["bg"] = "black"` but `Frame` is empty (you put all widgets directly to `root`) so it has no size and you will no see different background.

Answer (score 2):

You don't event put `Frame` in window (you don't use `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()`) but if you even put it in window it is empty so it will have no height and width so you will no see difference.

Better use `root` for this but you need `self.root` to access it in other function and then you can do

```
self.root['bg'] = 'green'
```

---

```
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: not preferred
import tkinter as tk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("250x300-1200-400")
        #self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        #self.frame.pack()

        # input field stored
        self.input_a = tk.StringVar()

        # input field
        input_color_changer = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.input_a)
        input_color_changer.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Run", command=self.color_changer)
        button.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def color_changer(self): # PEP8: lower_case_names for methods/functions/variables
        input_b = self.input_a.get()

        if input_b == "b":
            print("BLACK") # CHANGE COLOR OF FRAME TO BLACK
            self.root['bg'] = 'black'
        if input_b == "g":
            print("GREEN") # CHANGE COLOR OF FRAME TO GREEN etc...
            self.root['bg'] = 'green'

Main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much furas. I began my programming journey a month ago and I'm learning with small projects.